# Run the .sql file in loop until condition is met

Tags: postgresql, rstudio

I have a .sql file running in RStudio via cronjob. The .sql file fetch data from underline database table, performs logical computations and loads data into another table. There are scenarios where underline table data loads in late thus the overall process return no records.

Is there a way to loop this run until the underline table data is there. So if the underline table data is null, run the process in next 5 mins and stop the loop once the data is found. Any suggestion please on how can I make this happen.

Thanks

Comment: Please share code you are already using, and show what you have tried

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I don’t have any R code to share since I am trying to figure out how can I achieve that.  The .sql file looks like this - insert into table a (select * from table b where value = ‘sql-data’).  If there is a value, the process execute and end. If not, it loops again to check the data.

Answer (score -1):

To construct a loop in your R script that periodically checks the underlying table for data, use the while loop and Sys.sleep function. Run your SQL script after data has been located to end the loop. Be sure you manage errors and take the impact on resources into account. Investigate other data availability notification options.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to run the .sql code by passing command in .r script file rather than doing it manually using dbsendquery or other dbcommand line. If there is, then I think I should be able to perform the steps you outlined.